# apply for loop within list components in r and binding list components in r

Tags: r, list, for-loop, bind

The following is sample data and part of function I have trouble with.

```
# data
Gr1 <- data.frame (group = rep(1:2, each = 2001), 
position = round (c(0, cumsum (rnorm (2000, 0.05, 0.08)), 0, 
cumsum (rnorm (2000, 0.05, 0.08)))))

 Gr2 <- data.frame (group = rep(1:2, each = 2001), 
 position = round (c(0, cumsum (rnorm (2000, 0.05, 0.08)), 0, 
  cumsum (rnorm (2000, 0.04, 0.08)))))

 Gr3 <- data.frame (group = rep(1:2, each = 2001), 
position = round (c(0, cumsum (rnorm (2000, 0.05, 0.08)), 0, 
 cumsum (rnorm (2000, 0.05, 0.08)))))

 groupobs = list(Gr1, Gr2, Gr3)
 grnames = c("A", "B", "C")
 spacing = c(0, 0.1, 0.3)


    # for loop 

    for (i in 1:length(groupobs)){
     groupobs[i]$sgrp <- grnames[i]
     groupobs[i]$y <-  groupobs[i]$group + spacing[i]
    }

    # binding of list components
    mydf <- data.frame (rbind (groupobs)
```

How can I achieve this ?

**Edit:** With above loop, I want to achieve the following manual process. I want to automate n number of dataframe, so that I do not need to write a lengthy steps:

Please note that each of dataframes in this have same name of variables. For each component dataframe I want perform the following tasks. If I do it without looping:

```
# for first dataframe with in list 
Gr1$sgrp <- grnames[1]
Gr1$y <- Gr1$group + spacing[1]

# for second dataframe in the list
Gr2$sgrp <- grnames[2]
Gr2$y <- Gr1$group + spacing[2]

# for third dataframe in the list
Gr3$sgrp <- grnames[3]
Gr3$y <- Gr1$group + spacing[3]

mydf <- data.frame (rbind (Gr1, Gr2, Gr3))
```

Comment: @ttmaccer thanks for the comment please see my edits, hope I have expained enough to clearify what I want to acheive and avoiding the down vote on this !

Comment: I am with ttmaccer, just drop a note that please improve your question is I think bestway to go ...downvote and close vote without giving time to my opinion seems to too harsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maybe be way off here but

```
mydf<-mapply(function(a,b,c){a$sgrp<-b;a$y<-c;a},groupobs,grnames,spacing,SIMPLIFY = F)
mydf<-do.call("rbind",mydf)
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   12006 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ group   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ position: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ sgrp    : chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 $ y       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

might be what you are after.............

EDIT: changed to hopefully produce dataframe

thanks to @jon

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was expected dataframes binded into one. However the above fuction nicely created a list of lists.

Comment: may be you would like do.call("rbind", mydf) over mydf<-rbind(mydf[[1]],mydf[[2]],mydf[[3]]) to automate the process with n levels